# Can the word "unsolicited" be used as a verb?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

Consider the following:

> He replied to us even when *not solicited/asked*.

Can *not solicited* be replaced with *unsolicited*?

Answer (score 5):

*Solicited* can be seen as a verb in the way you want to use it. It’s a non-finite verb, which means it doesn't show tense or person. There is no verb **unsolicit*, so there cannot be a verb *unsolicited*, which must therefore be considered an adjective. By analogy, *solicited* can also be seen as an adjective as well as a verb.

Comment: I agree that *solicit* is the citation form for the verb from which *solicited* derives, but I cannot imagine **unsolicit*. Not all adjectives of the *-ed* variety derive from a verb, and so should not be called verbs. I’m spacing on the technical name for these, though. Gimme a second and I’ll dig up a proper reference.

Comment: @tchrist: You're quite right, and I've edited my answer.

Comment: Still digging, but I think I’m thinking of something else. A good example of what I’m talking about is *fanged visage*, which does not presuppose a verb *to ∗fang*, despite being an *-ed* adjective. **What is that sort of thing called?** Regarding *unsolicited*, there’s a verb there but it is *solicit* not *∗unsolicit*, because the *un-* was applied to *solicited*, not the *-ed* to *∗unsolicit*. This is like how an *unbroken series* doesn’t posit a verb *to ∗unbreak*.

Comment: The OED’s second entry for *-ed* is the one I was thinking of. Citing OED2: “is appended to sbs. in order to form adjs. connoting the possession or the presence of the attribute or thing expressed by the sb..In mod.Eng., and even in ME., the form affords no means of distinguishing between the genuine examples of this suffix and those ppl. adjs. in -ed1 which are ultimately f. sbs. through unrecorded vbs..The suffix is now added without restriction to any sb. from which it is desired to form an adj. with the sense ‘possessing, provided with, characterized by’ (something);” No special name? Hm.

Comment: @tchrist: Thank you. Do you agree that whereas 'unsolicited' can be analysed only as an adjective, 'solicited' can be analyzed either as an adjective or as a non-finite verb?

Comment: Yes, I do agree with all that.

Comment: This answer aims to be technically correct but does not answer the central thrust of the OP's question which is "can I use this word here?"   The answer is **yes** (although sure, it'll have its adjective hat on rather than any verb hat) whereas this answer superficially appears be an equivocal no.

Answer (score 4):

According to OED *unsolicited* is an adjective not verb and means *not asked for; given or done voluntarily,* which could perfectly work in your context.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can certainly use "unsolicited" in that way.  I'm not sure whether I'd consider it a verb though; I'm trying to imagine how one might *unsolicit* something or someone.

Comment: I don't think the word "unsolicited" really works here.  Had the sentence "He replied to us when solicited" would imply "He replied to us when [a replier was] solicited".  The people doing the soliciting were not soliciting the person as an individual, but were soliciting a replier, and the individual in question was one.  Adding "not" maintains the sentence structure.  Using "unsolicited", however, doesn't work IMHO, since it would imply that the individual (rather than the reply) was unsolicited.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the word "**not solicited**" in the original statement is fine.

However, most dictionaries classify "**unsolicited**" only as an adjective and with the meaning of "[not searched or asked for.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unsolicited)"

So if you want to use "**unsolicited**," to be safe, I'd suggest:

> He gave us a reply even when unsolicited.

Or,

> He gave us a reply though unsolicited.

Comment: I don't think your proposed constructs really work, since "unsolicited" looks like it modifies to "He" [via an implied "he was"] rather than modifying "gave" or "a reply".  Better would be "He gave us an message, unsolicited".  Note that "unsolicited reply" is somewhat oxymoronic, given that the existence of a "reply" implies the existence of something which prompts it [and thus effectively "solicits" it].

Answer (score 0):

It's an example of a past participle ending (-ed) being applied to a noun (not a verb) to create an adjective. E.g. *Certificated Bailiff*. No such verb as *to certificate* but it is a perfectly logical way to express *in receipt of a certificate*.

Comment: See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/can-the-word-unsolicited-be-used-as-a-verb#comment147999_75968).